# make subdomain on IIS point to specific folder on other server

Tags: windows, iis, dns, subdomain, windows-server-2008

i have a domain that i have full access to the IIS, and it hosts the main website.
i want to make a subdomain retrive files from another server (Media Temple grid hosting), in an specific path.

for example:
mysubdomain.domain.com (my IIS server)
get files from www.otherdomainandserver.com/sites/comunidade (Media Temple hosting)

i was able to set the IP address on the A Record, but i can't point to the correct folder that has the files, the specific path.

any thoughts on that?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Under your main domain's (domain.com) website right click and add new "Virtual Directory".
2. On Add Virtual Directory dialog give whatever name (mysubdomain) you want to give in "alias" field. In physical path field give network folder's path and click ok.
3. Right click on Virtual directory created in step 2 and select "Convert to Application"
4. Make sure that app pool identity under which your subdomain app is running has at least read access to network folder.

Remember you can not map your subdomain application's physical path to virtual path from some other application's virtual path i.e.(www.otherdomainandserver.com/sites/comunidade). It has to be physical path e.g. \\myotherserver\myfoldertomap

Comment: thanks, @Pankaj Kapare. turns out this DNS was configured by my client's IT area, even when the server was under my control.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to ignore the subdirectory. I added app.test to the hosts file, and I added app.test as a virtual directory according to your instructions, and I told IIS that it should use /www/app as the root, but instead, it loads /www as the root.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way and that is less technical but let me share with you hope that will solve your problem.

Domain which you want to park to another server subfolder need to change the dns with another server DNS and addon that domain to the server where you want to point...while doing the addon process your cpanel would ask where you would like to point the directory and save this...BINGO the work is done you domain is pointed to another server directory.